# Make Sequence Column Increment Based On Conditions?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

**Background Information**

So here is the background to this question. Currently we have multiple bill of material number identifiers( UNPN,UDEN,UXXN,etc.) Each with its own sequence number (UNPN0001,UNPN0002,UNPN0003,etc.)

When a user requests a new bill of material number, lets say a new UNPN number. If the last number was UNPN0003 then the user should be able to reserve UNPN0004.

**My Initial Thought:**

So initially I figured, I could simply create a sequence column in a table. So if we had a UNPN table, we could easily add a new record and sequence it automatically and return the combination of UNPN + Generated Sequence number.

**The Problem:**

So the problem I identified is that for this method, we currently have 50+ different bill of material identifiers. So this would mean I would have to create 1 table for each identifier with its own auto sequence column.

**What I am looking for:**

I would prefer to avoid creating 50+ different tables. I am not sure if there is a different schema I could use for my database or if I should abandon this method all together for something else. I don't believe you can have multiple sequence columns in a table that only sequence based on what is input, of course I don't have a full understanding of what all is possible

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: How frequent are your inserts? You'd want to make sure you got ACID stuff right, but one thing you could consider is just having a table that contains rows for each bill type and the latest sequence number -- when you do an insert, just use that sequence number and increment it for the specific bill type.

Comment: Create a table to hold the bills and sequence, so for each request get the last sequence of that bill increment and store back

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have thought about this and I would prefer to avoid incrementing the value myself. If two requests are made at the same time, it throws in the possibility of duplicates. Id prefer the database increment the sequence itself. @Slothario

Comment: What if you wrote a stored procedure that would do the inserts for you? You could create a sequence for every possible order type, and you wouldn't have to maintain any kind of counts yourself.

Comment: @Slothario Wouldn't that mean the server still needs to maintain the count? Even with a store procedure, can't you run into the same problem? If two requests are made at the same time, the stored procedure grabs current count and increments it? Excuse me if that sounds like a stupid question, I have 0 familiarity with how stored procedures work.

Comment: If you are trying to achieve 'gapless' numbers for each BOM code, (or gapless numbers for any use at all) you are on a fool's errand.  An autoincrement column is just a method that automatically ties a column to a sequence. And oracle has _never_ guaranteed gapless sequences.  If you try to write your own method of creating a sequence, you will run into the same inherent multi-user issues that prevent oracle from guaranteeing gapless sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've indicated that you are using Oracle.  Oracle has a database level objects known as sequences made for this sort of thing.  They are very performant.  You would want to make one sequence for each of your identifiers. You only need to do this once for each identifier.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE UNPN;  -- Starts a 1 by default
CREATE SEQUENCE UDEN START WITH 50;
CREATE SEQUENCE UXXN MAXVALUE 9999 CYCLE; -- This one will recycle back to 0001 after it hits 9999
```

Next when ever you need a new value for a given sequence you can just select it:

```
SELECT 'UNPN'||TO_CHAR(UNPN.NEXTVAL,'FM0000') FROM DUAL;
```

To make it easier/more dynamic you can define a function to get the new value by name:

```
create or replace function get_named_seq(p_sequence varchar2) return varchar2
is
  l_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_Result varchar2(30);
begin
  select 'select '''||sequence_name||'''||to_char('||sequence_name||'.nextval,''FM0000'') from dual'
    into l_sql
    from user_sequences
   where sequence_name = upper(p_sequence);

  execute immediate l_sql
     into l_Result;
   return l_result;
end;
/
```

The above function will throw a NO_DATA_FOUND exception if the requested sequence doesn't exist, and even though it's using dynamic SQL it should be safe from SQL Injection since the actual dynamic SQL statement never directly touches the input parameter.  you would use it like this or any where you can use a function:

```
INSERT into MyTable (ID, Data) values (get_named_seq('UXXN'), 'some data');
```

Comment: I apologize I made a mistake. We are using Microsoft SQL server databases.

Comment: Nevermind, I just found out SQL Server started support on sequences in 2012.